# Angular: Trying to pop an array based on current iteration of ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have a ngFor loop that generates a component I built as below;

```
<app-body *ngFor = 'let card of cardElements; index as i' (deleteCardEmit) = 'cardDeletion()' [currentCard] = 'card'></app-body>
```

In my TS file the function 'cardDeletion' does the following;

```
cardDeletion(){
    this.cardElements.pop()
  }
```

I basically want the pop to only delete the component the 'deleteCardEmit' originates from. Anything I place in the 'cardDeletion' function will work from the code below;

Button in the child component:

```
<button (click) = 'deleteCard()' > Delete job </button>
```

The @Output emitter:

```
@Output() deleteCardEmit = new EventEmitter;
```

The 'deleteCard' function:

```
deleteCard(){
    this.deleteCardEmit.emit();
  }
```

Apologies if my question does not make sense I've only been doing Web development for a week at this point with little prior programming experience. I had originally thought I could pass the index I get from my ngFor into the pop as so:

```
this.cardElements.pop(i)
```

But no luck - any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you have too much stuff going on and its hard to tell what you are asking. normally within your ngFor statement, you would want something like this: `*ngFor = 'let card of cardElements; ' (click) = "cardDeletion(card)" [currentCard] = 'card'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach it in this way: emit the element to delete, filter the actual array with the element to be removed from it.

So:

```html
  <app-body *ngFor = 'let card of cardElements; index as i' (deleteCardEmit) = 'cardDeletion(card)' [currentCard] = 'card'></app-body>
```

```js
public cardDeletion(card) {
  this.cardElements = this.cardElements.filter(currentCard => card !== currentCard);
}
```

In this way you are filtering the element and stimolate the digest to refresh the page

Comment: This seems to work thank you so much - I can't work out what the line is doing in my function though with the this.cardElements = etc but thank you.

Comment: `this.cardElements.filter(currentCard => card !== currentCard);` is iterating through every element of `cardElements` and return a **new** array that satisfy the condition inside the function. For more details see [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)